# How to trigger filtering on React Table by using a filter component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, html-table

Im using React Table(https://react-table.js.org) for populating a table with data from an API call. Now I want to filter two columns in the table. I have implemented a filter component which lets the user select the filter options and it updates the state. My question is how to link the two components? When I click Apply button on my filter component the table has to show only the columns which match the filter criteria. Im aware that React Table(https://react-table.js.org)provides some APIs to listen to callback for filtering, however Im unable to implement that.
Also, both the components are present in the same js file and dont have a parent component. Should there be a common parent component? I prefer managing state locally and not use any state management libraries. Im not using Redux, so what is the best way to implement the filter functionality with local state management?

This is my state function:

```
    const makeDefaultState = () => ({
      Name: "",
      ID: "",
      IdMenu: '',
      NameMenu: '',
      filtered: [],
      open: false,
    });
```

The callback function to set state of the dropdown:

```
    getIdMenu = (IdMenu) => {
      console.log(IdMenu);
      this.setState({ IdMenu });
     }

   getNameMenu = (NameMenu) => {
     console.log(NameMenu);
     this.setState({ NameMenu });
    }
```

My table component is as follows:

```
     <ReactTable
data={tableData}
loading={this.props.loading}
showPagination={false}
filterable
defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row) =>
  String(row[filter.id]) === filter.value}
columns={[
  {
    columns: [
      {
        sortable: false,
        filterable: false,
        Header: "Id",
        accessor: "resourceId",
        headerStyle: {
          background: '#ECEFF1',
        },
      },
      {
        sortable: false,
        filterable: false,
        Header: "Name",
        accessor: "Name",
        id: "Name",
        headerStyle: {
          background: '#ECEFF1',
        },
      },
 </ReactTable>
```

The dropdown Filter Component is as follows:

```
     <RaisedButton
          onClick={this.handleTouchTap}
          label="FILTER"
          labelColor="#26A69A"
      />
      <Popover
          open={this.state.open}
          anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
          anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'bottom' }}
          targetOrigin={{ horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top' }}
          onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
          animation={PopoverAnimationVertical}
      >
        <Menu>
          <MenuItem
              primaryText={"NAME - " + this.state.NameMenu}
              rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
              menuItems={[
                <MenuItem 
                  primaryText="OPTION 1" 
                  onClick={() =>
                this.getNameMenu('OPTION 1')
              }
                />,
                <Divider />,
                <MenuItem primaryText="OPTION 2"
                  onClick={() =>
                    this.getNameMenu('OPTION 2')
              }
                />,
              ]}
          />

          <Divider />

          <MenuItem
              primaryText={"ID -   " + this.state.IdMenu}
              rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
              menuItemStyle={{ backgroundcolor: '#E0F2F1' }}
              menuItems={[
                <MenuItem primaryText="1" onClick={() =>
                this.getIdMenu('1')
              }
                />,
                <Divider />,
                <MenuItem primaryText="2" onClick={() =>
                this.getIdMenu('2')
              }
                />,
          <RaisedButton
              label="APPLY"
              style={{ margin: 2, width: '60px' }}
              labelColor="#FAFAFA"
              backgroundColor="#26A69A"
              onClick={() => 
              }
          />
          <RaisedButton
              label="CANCEL"
              style={{ margin: 22, width: '60px' }}
              labelColor="#26A69A"
              onClick={() =>
                this.resetState()
            }
          />
```